# Filling ellipse disappears other graphics elements

Tags: ios, uiview, drawing

I am trying to draw some graphics elements in a UIView inside drawRect method. Code is attached, when I run this code the circle filled with color makes other line disappear.

```
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y);
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60+x,100+y,100,80);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGColorRelease(color);
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem. Closer look at documentation on CGContextFillEllipseInRect function has totally disappointed me:

> **Discussion**
>
> As a side effect when you call this function, Quartz clears the
>        current path

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextFillEllipseInRect